# sort a list in python by order of two other lists

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have an interesting problem for which I could not find any solution yet. 
Having two lists with the same values in a different order. I reorder one list so, that the list gets identical. That's fine but I need to reorder also an additional third list with the same key.

I'm not able to use zip nor enumerate in my code to retrieve the new Index of the second list.

```
first=[(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3)]
second=[(2,2,2),(3,3,3),(1,1,1)]
third=[2,3,1]

second=sorted(second,key=first.index)

print(second)
```

`[(1,1,1),(2,2,2),(3,3,3)]`

```
d = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(second), key=lambda x:first.index)]
```

d should be `(2,0,1)` but it is not working

the goal for the third list is to become: `[1,2,3]`

Comment: I understood up to the last sentence. Why should third be [1, 2, 3]?

Comment: Is `third` always similar to `second`, i.e. 2.. 3... 1..?

Comment: No, I see... my example is to much simplified... The values of these list can be any float in no specific order, except that the values in first and second are the same but in different order. Third can be seen as objects belonging to the items in original second list.

Comment: Yes, third is always similar to second but with totaly different values. My goal is to roeder third the same way as i can do for second.

Answer (score 0):

To get `[1, 2, 3]`, use:

```
third = sorted(third, key=list(map(lambda x: x[0],first)).index)
```

To get `[2, 0, 1]`, use:

```
d = sorted(range(second), key=lambda x: first[x])
```

Comment: thanks, but in my real code I cannot use values from thirst to sort third. I need to use the same reorder index as used for second.

Comment: I retrieve following error for d: TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Answer (score 0):

This question is solved.
One can fetch the index from re-ordered "second" as shown under the LINK, and use this indexlist to sort any other list.

[Sort python list by order of another list AND retrieve old index](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56020701/sort-python-list-by-order-of-another-list-and-retrieve-old-index)