# Sort python list by order of another list AND retrieve old index

Tags: python, list, sorting, indexing

Trying to retrieve the index of sorted list "second". 
"second" contains same values as "first" and will be reordered to become identical order as "first". I'm looking for an indexlist "d" which contains the the reordered indexes from old "second".

tryied to retrieve "d" with zip or enumerate, but failed.

```
first= [(11.373,0.354,6.154),(22.354,0.656,0.664),(33.654,33.546,31.131)]
second=[(22.354,0.656,0.664),(33.654,33.546,31.131),(11.373,0.354,6.154)]

second=sorted(second,key=first.index)

print(first)
print(second)
[(11.373, 0.354, 6.154), (22.354, 0.656, 0.664), (33.654, 33.546, 31.131)]
[(11.373, 0.354, 6.154), (22.354, 0.656, 0.664), (33.654, 33.546, 31.131)]
```

Here "second" become same order as "first". Cool.
But how can I retrieve the reorderd Indexlist "d" from "second"?

I tried like:
    d = [i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(second), key=first.index)]

In this example "d" should become [2,0,1]

This type of key is somehow blocking the possibility to retriev the old index. Any recommendation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is one approach.

**Ex:**

```
first= [(11.373,0.354,6.154),(22.354,0.656,0.664),(33.654,33.546,31.131)]
second=[(22.354,0.656,0.664),(33.654,33.546,31.131),(11.373,0.354,6.154)]

temp = sorted(second,key=first.index)            #Sorted List. 
d = list(map(lambda x: second.index(x), temp))   #Fetch index from temp

print(first)
print(temp)
print(d)
```

**Output:**

```
[(11.373, 0.354, 6.154), (22.354, 0.656, 0.664), (33.654, 33.546, 31.131)]
[(11.373, 0.354, 6.154), (22.354, 0.656, 0.664), (33.654, 33.546, 31.131)]
[2, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Fetching the index this way is nice,That is doing the trick. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your question correctly, you can use `numpy` `argsort` and bypass the need for "second".

Here's a code snippet.

```
from pprint import pprint
import numpy

def main():
    first= [(11.373,0.354,6.154),(22.354,0.656,0.664),(33.654,33.546,31.131)]
    index_array= (numpy.argsort(first))
    for i in index_array:
        pprint(i.tolist())

if __name__== "__main__":
    main()
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 0]
[1, 2, 0]
[2, 1, 0]
```

Remember `index_array` contains the indexes into the original list so that if you use them in that order applied to the original list, the list is sorted.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` again to get the index in the original list, but (a) this might fail if there are duplicate elements, and (b) this has O(n²), twice. Instead, I'd suggest using `enumerate(first)` for first mapping elements to their indices, and then `sorting` the `(index, element)` pairs from `enumerate(second)`, using the indices from that map as a key, to get the sorted indices from `second`.

```
>>> ind = {x: i for i, x in enumerate(first)}
>>> [i for i, x in sorted(enumerate(second), key=lambda t: ind[t[1]])]
[2, 0, 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help:

```
sorted(range(len(second)),key=second.__getitem__)
```

also to get both item and index

```
sorted_indices, sorted_items = zip(*sorted([(i,e) for i,e in enumerate(second)], key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

Comment: Thanks, bu not exactely what I was looking for, because this code is simple sorting and not considering the order of "first".